# title and legend not appearing in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I've consulted the "Getting Started Guide" for MATLAB 7, and I was certain my code for this assignment was correct, but when I run it the legend and title do not display.

My code is:

```
x= [-1:0.1:1];

a=sin(x);

b=cos(x);

c=tan(x);

plot (x,a, 'r-',x,b, 'k:',x,c, 'bo')

legend (sin(x),cos(x), tan(x))

title ('Trig Functions')
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the text you want to put in the legend in ' ' (damn I forgot the name of these sorry) otherwise MATLAB throws an error since it expects strings as arguments:

```
legend ('sin(x)','cos(x)', 'tan(x)','Location','best')
```

Doing so will remove the error and display the title correctly, which you have put between ' '. Note that I used the `Location` property to put the legend in the best possible way since it was hiding part of the plots. You can put it wherever you want with other values; look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html?searchHighlight=legend) for details.

Comment: They're just called single quotation marks my friend :)